# Open Facebook app when users clicks on HTML like button?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook like button on a HTML page that has been generated through Facebook:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" 
data-layout="standard" 
data-action="like" 
data-size="small" 
data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="true">
</div>
```

Now a lot of people are logged into the Facebook app on mobile but not the web version.

Is it possible to open the Facebook app when a user clicks on the like button and let them like with their logged in account from the app when they click on the button from the webpage?

I can remember from a while ago that is was possible in Android at least to open certain apps from a webpage. I am not sure if this is possible for IOS or if this is still possible.

Comment: Do you mean you want to open the Facebook app only? Or also like the page automaticly?

Comment: Well the normal behavior is to open the page in the webbrowser when you want to like it but I want it to open in the app whenever that is possible(if possible at all).